# Hoffman and Kunze , linear algebra Sec 3.2 exercise 9

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on the finite-dimensional space $V.$ Suppose there is a linear operator $U$ on $V$ such that $TU=I.$ Prove that $T$ is invertible and $U=T^{-1}.$

Attempt: Let $\dim V=n$ and $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^n$ a basis for $V$. We claim that $\{U(\alpha_i)_{i=1}^n\}$ is a basis for $V.$ If not then there exists scalars $c_i$'s $\in F$ not all zero such that $\sum c_iU(\alpha_i)=0.$ Applying $T$ on both sides we get $\sum c_iTU(\alpha_i)=\sum c_i\alpha_i=0,$ a contradiction. Thus $\{U(\alpha_i)_{i=1}^n\}$ is a basis for $V.$

Now we observe that $T[U(\alpha_i)]=\alpha_i$ since $TU=I.$ We infer that $T$ and $U$ are invertible since they map basis vectors to basis vectors. It remains to show that $U=T^{-1}.$

**Can I say that $U=T^{-1}$ using $TU=I$?**
I am not sure if I can use this since I don't know if inverses are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose at this point you just need to show that $UT = I$ as well. You can use $TU = I$ and the fact that $T^{-1}$ exists for this:

\begin{align*}
TU &= I \\
TUT &= IT = T \\
T^{-1}TUT &= T^{-1}T \\
UT &= I
\end{align*}

Comment: I disagree. If we say $T^{-1}$ exists then we need not use $UT = I$ because we're assuming what we need to show.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what exactly the author thought needs to be demonstrated. Perhaps I should have said that the $T^{-1}$ I was using was a left-inverse and we are proving that it is in fact $U$.

Comment: @KenDuna I think you are right. Since it is an elementary theorem on functions that if left and right inverses exist, they must be equal and unique.

Answer (score 1):

As $TU =I$, therefore $TU$ is onto. This implies $T$ is onto.
As $V$ is finite dimensional therefore this also shows that $T$ is one-one. Thus, $T$ is invertible and inverse has to be $U$.

Comment: You are right. I was not sure why inverse has to be **only** $U.$ Now I realise that it is an elementary theorem on functions that if left and right inverses exist, they must be equal and unique.